# Tetrahedron with Three Right Angles at Three Different Vertices?

Tags: geometry

A tetrahedron, for which the embedding polyhedron is a cube, has at least three surfaces with a right angle. There are three types:

1. Three right angles all at one common vertex, (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), which is a trirectangular tetrahedron.
2. Four right angles with a pair at each of two vertices, (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), which is a semi-orthocentric tetrahedron.
3. Three right angles at three separate vertices, (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1).

How would this last one be described?

Are any other types possible?